# Unable to use gettext i18n with ngx-translate-po-http-loader in JHipster project

Tags: angular, internationalization, jhipster, gettext, ngx-translate

I'm trying to use gettext po files for i18n in our Angular application which was generated with JHipster, but I am not able to make it work. As it already uses ngx-translate, I've added [ngx-translate-extract](https://github.com/biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract) and [ngx-translate-po-http-loader](https://github.com/biesbjerg/ngx-translate-po-http-loader) to the project.

As an example I have the following html code for a logout button:

```
<button mat-menu-item (click)="logout();" id="logout">
    <mat-icon>power_settings_new </mat-icon>
    <span>{{'Log out' | translate}}</span>
</button>
```

Extracting the i18n key to a pot template file works fine. Out of the template, I've created a german translation file and place it underneath `src/main/webapp/i18n/po/de.po`

In my `app.module.ts` (complete file: https://pastebin.com/T4Bi11Vg), I've added the following snippet

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
 ]
 ...
 export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
     return new TranslatePoHttpLoader(http, 'src/main/webapp/i18n/po', '.po');
}
```

In addition I've deleted the existing `de` folder underneath `src/main/webapp/i18n` to ensure that it will not take the old translation from the json files.

When I debug the generated `language.helper.ts` I can see that it registered the `TranslatePoHttpLoader` correctly, but still it does not show the german translation.

[debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi0gi.png)